# Angular validation within dynamic forms

Tags: angular, validation, angular-material, nested, nested-forms

I'm using Angular Material and trying to display the errors. The problem is that I can't connect to the actual value.

This is my component.ts code:

```
myForm!: FormGroup;

constructor(private fb: FormBuilder) { }

  ngOnInit() {
    this.myForm= this.fb.group({
      users: this.fb.array([])
    });
  }

//getting users as a form arr
  get Users(){
    return this.myForm.get('users') as FormArray;
  }

//adding new dynamic forms
 addUser(){
      const user = this.fb.group({
      fname: [null, Validators.required],
      lname: ['', Validators.required],
      updateOn: 'blur'
    })
    this.Users.push(user);
  }
```

And this is my html template:

```
<div *ngFor="let user of Users.controls; let i = index" [formGroupName]="i">
<mat-form-field>
  <input matInput placeholder="first name" formControlName="fname">

  <mat-error *ngIf="user['controls'].fname.hasError('required')">
        Enter the first name
   </mat-error>
</mat-form-field>
</div>
```

I also tried to write get function for this code, but it turned out like this:

```
 get User() {
    return (this.myForm.controls.users as FormGroup).controls;
  }
```

And then tried to write in html like:

```
*ngIf="user['User'].fname.hasError('required')"
```

it still shows this error: **error TS7052: Element implicitly has an 'any' type because type 'AbstractControl' has no index signature. Did you mean to call 'get'?**

How can I bind to those values?

Comment: Is my answer helpful for you?

Answer (score 1):

You have written condition on mat-error is wrong. It should be as following:

```
<div [formGroup]="myForm">
  <div formArrayName="users">
    <div *ngFor="let user of Users.controls; let i = index" [formGroupName]="i">
      <mat-form-field>
        <input matInput placeholder="first name" formControlName="fname">
        <mat-error *ngIf="user?.get('fname')?.errors">
          Enter the first name
        </mat-error>
      </mat-form-field>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: If you're using material and mat-error and you has an unique error you needn't use `*ngIf`, material error is yet take account of this